# how can I play Heroes Evolved on Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: wine, games

So I had this game called Heroes Evolved but it require windows.
 So I use Wine and it doesn't work. I also have try using PlayOnLinux it doesn't work. while using wine I get this type of error [installation request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltCqq.png)  [Installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVlsx.png)

Comment: can you add more detail? does it install? what error are you getting? Are you using a 32-bit wine prefix?

Comment: If name ot the game is correct, Wine AppDB [does not include this game](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=application&sTitle=Browse+Applications&iItemsPerPage=25&iPage=1&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true). You may try to install it with PlayOnLinux (`sudo apt-get install playonlinux`).

Comment: I have try install it by PlayOnLinux it when well. then I click the shortcut on PlayOnLinux it's doing fine but after I log in It turned out blank. @N0rbert